# Conversion error when passing vector of type uint8_t to std::fill() in C++

Tags: c++

I am using the below code snippet to pass vector of type "uint8_t" to std::fill()

```
size_t actual_size = 10;
std::vector<uint8_t> response;
std::fill(response.begin(), response.end() + actual_size, 0);
```

But i am getting the below warnings.

```
 message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::fill<std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>>,int>(const _FwdIt,const _FwdIt,const int &)' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Ty=uint8_t,
            _FwdIt=std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<uint8_t>>>
        ]

 warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'const _Ty' to 'unsigned char', possible loss of data
        with
        [
            _Ty=int
        ]
```

How to resolve this warning.

Comment: `std::fill(..., static_cast<uint8_t>(0))`? Btw: the code you've posted has undefined behaviour: `std::fill` won't resize `response`; all `std::fill` does here is trying to set the first 10 elements of an empty list; for this scenario using [`std::vector::resize`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) would be preferrable, which would also fix the warning.

Comment: If you really want to see warnings about code whose meaning is well defined and that does exactly what you want, you can get rid of this particular warning by casting that '0' to `std::uint8_t`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting the warning is because when filling `0`(an `int`) to a `vector<uint8_t>`, you are implicitly converting an `int` to an `uint8_t`, which can potentially have data loss if the original `int` is not in the valid range of `uint8_t`.

To solve it, you can either create a `uint8_t` directly, or manually cast the `int` to `uint8_t`.

---

Also, when you do:

```cpp
std::fill(vec.begin(), vec.end() + some_size, some_value)
```

You are literally filling elements pass the end iterator, without resizing the vector, which is likely not what you wanted.

Instead, you should use `fill_n` to specify the number of element to fill, and use `back_inserter` to push it to the vector:

```cpp
std::fill_n(std::back_inserter(vec), some_size, some_value);
```

Or you can simply initialize the vector with the appropriate data filled:

```cpp
std::vector<std::uint8_t> vec(some_size, some_value);
```

Or even zero initialize them, since you were going to assign them to `0`s:

```cpp
std::vector<std::uint8_t> vec(some_size);
```